# Why does my app's icon appear before my splash screen image in android jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I made a dictionary app and there is a splash screen from the dictionary app , and I show an image on the splash screen. When I completed the app, I changed the icon of the app and when I change the icon of the app, this icon appears on the screen for a while before my picture on the splash screen. However, before changing the icon of the app, such a thing did not happen when it was default. I want to change this, so I want only the picture I showed on the splash screen to be displayed. By the way, the icon of the application and the picture I show on the splash screen are different from each other.

Have you encountered something like this before?

**here is my splash screen**

```
@Composable
fun SplashScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel : SplashScreenViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {


    val context: Context = LocalContext.current



    val scale = remember {
        Animatable(0f)
    }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
        scale.animateTo(
            targetValue = 1f,
            animationSpec = tween(
                durationMillis = 500,
                easing = {
                    OvershootInterpolator(2f).getInterpolation(it)
                }
            )
        )


        delay(3000L)

        navController.navigate(Screen.MainScreen.route)
    }


    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {

        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_splash_screen_dictionary2),
            contentDescription = "Logo",
            modifier = Modifier.scale(scale.value)
        )
    }


}
```

**EDIT**

**SOLVED**

I solved the problem. Making a splash screen with the SplashScreen composable screen is the wrong approach. I did this because I saw it this way in many places and projects, but here Android adds the app's icon for the automatic splash screen if we do not use the splash API. Of course, since I do not use the splash API, as suggested by @Darian-Cătălin Cucer, but since my first screen is SplashScreen, the app icon determined by Android appears first and then my first screen, SplashScreen, appears. I solved this problem with the site suggested by @Darian-Cătălin Cucer.

Comment: That sounds like you are seeing [the system-supplied splash screen](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen) on Android 12+.

Comment: thank you for answer I looked at the link but I don't understand exactly what I need to do, can you explain a little more?

Comment: okey I couldnt understand what is the problem but when I try my app in the real phone it works properly but when I try the emulator it doesnt work properly. I think it probably won't be a problem. Thanks for your answer

Comment: [Check this, gentleman](https://developersancho.medium.com/jetpack-compose-splash-screen-api-36ca40c6196b)

Comment: In case the android logo is visible before splash screen which I was facing I have added     <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item> inside the style tag of app theme. and it solved my problem